# Hide Window from taskbar without using WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW

Tags: c, winapi

I have a main Window and an About Window, The About Window is opened from the main Window, but the problem is that the About Window is shown in the taskbar!

I have found that in order to hide a Window from the taskbar, I can use the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` style, but I don't want the About Window to have this style, so is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplifying a little, a window is represented in the taskbar if:

- It is not owned and does not have the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW extended style, or
- It has the WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style.

So, the solution for you is to make the window be owned. It should be owned by the main window of your application. Pass the main window handle as `hWndParent` when you create the about window.

```
hWndAbout := CreateWindowEx(..., hWndMainWindow, ...);
                                 ^^^ hWndParent
```

As well as resolving the problem with the taskbar, setting the owner will also ensure that the about window is always shown on top of the main window.

Comment: In addition, the parent window does not need to be your main window or any visible window. If you simply want a window to hide in taskbar, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar#managing-taskbar-buttons , you can first create a window without showing it, and pass its HWND as parent when you create the new window.